# Как сделать кнопку Tkinter так чтобы она открывала другое окно

Tags: python, tkinter, datetime

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('270x450')

button_1 = Button(text='Часы', width=10, height=5, font=('Roman 10'))
button_1.place(x=50, y=50)

button_2 = Button(text='Календарь', width=12, height=6, font=('Roman 8'))
button_2.place(x=150, y=50)

button_3 = Button(text='Настройки', width=10, height=5, font=('Roman 9'))
button_3.place(x=50, y=150)

button_4 = Button(text='Игра', width=10, height=5, font=('Roman 10'))
button_4.place(x=150, y=150)

window.mainloop()
```

А вот код приложения, которая кнопка должна открывать:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Часы")
a = Label(root, font=("Gabriola", 20))


def update_time():
    root.geometry('270x450+{}+{}'.format(500, 400))
    a.config(text=f"{datetime.now():%H:%M:%S}")
    root.after(100, update_time)  # Запланировать выполнение этой же функции через 100 миллисекунд

a = Label(root, font=("helvetica", 40))
a.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
update_time()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Не забудьте отметить один из ответов принятым, если он вам помог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второе окно создаете через `Toplevel` вместо `Tk`, оборачиваете его создание в функцию, эту функцию вызываете через кнопку:

```
import tkinter as tk

from datetime import datetime


def clock():
    clock_window = tk.Toplevel()
    clock_window.title("Часы")
    label = tk.Label(clock_window, font=("helvetica", 40))
    label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    def update_time():
        clock_window.geometry('270x450+{}+{}'.format(500, 400))
        label.config(text=f"{datetime.now():%H:%M:%S}")
        clock_window.after(100, update_time)  # Запланировать выполнение этой же функции через 100 миллисекунд

    update_time()


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('270x450')

button_1 = tk.Button(text='Часы', width=10, height=5, font=('Roman 10'), command=clock)
button_1.place(x=50, y=50)

...

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Где приложение часы находится не знаю, но вреде должно открыть файл

```
import subprocess

button_1 = Button(text='Часы', width=10, height=5, font=('Roman 10'), 
command=open_button)

# Точно не помню как атрибут command выглядит

def open_button():
    subprocess.Popen(["Путь к фалйлу"])

    # Можно еще - import os; os.system('"Путь к файлу"')
    # ; означает, что код можно записать в 1 строку (тоже самое, что и enter)
```

Comment: кста приложение часы надо еще скачать.